# Can I login multiple user accounts at the same time with virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox

I've installed Windows Enterprise server 2008 R2 on Oracle virtualbox and created 3 users. I wonder if there is a way to login and manipulate 3 user accounts at the same time, I don't want to switch them continuously.

Answer (score 1):

Just use on your host system a rdp client (remmina works fine in linux) and open three windows, one for each user.

Comment: I installed Virtual expansion package to use RDP but then I could only make 1 remote windows ?

Comment: Don't connect to the VirtualBox RDP server.  Connect to the actual Windows machine.  This will require that either (1) the VM uses bridged networking, so you can directly access on your network, or (2) the VM uses NAT networking with port forwarding configured to forward port 3389 (the RDP service port) into the VM.